# CSS ribbon effect for footer

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

So I made a ribbon effect on my navigation no problem, but when I tried to do the same thing with the footer, I ran into issues with the right fold not appearing. This is the css I wrote for the footer ribbon.

```
.ribbon {
    background:#8346ab;
    padding:1em;
    margin-left:-40px;
    padding-left:40px;
    padding-right:40px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
.ribbon:after, .ribbon:before{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    border:10px solid #1f364c;
    border-top-width:0;
}
.ribbon:after{
    right:0;
    border-right-color:transparent;
    border-top-width:0;
    border-left-width:0;
    border-right-width:40px;
}
.ribbon:before {
    left:0;
    border-left-color:transparent;
    border-top-width:0;
    border-right-width:0;
    border-left-width:40px;
}
```

This should have worked but not sure why the right fold isn't showing up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post a complete code example that allows us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Your ribbon is working just fine http://jsbin.com/EwiGaDaJ/1/edit The problem lies somewhere else in your CSS

Comment: This makes me sad. I'm making changes to a drupal site, so if something here is conflicting, I need to dig thru a bunch of other folders to find what the problem could be. Thank you for checking it thou.